# I want to image or copy all my external hard drive content to a folder in my pc

Tags: hard-drive

I have a problem with my external hard drive and I want to forma it, I tried to copy all its content but the operation is hanging. How can I copy all my external data to a folder so I can access it or copy it again after i format it.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: what command you have used?

Comment: what's wrong with drag and drop? if it hangs after a while do it in smaller parts...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rsync` with the `-v` option. It will show you a progress bar, and if it happens to get stuck at some point, you'll know exactly at file it gets stuck.
To use rsync:

1. Insert your external hard drive. Navigate to the folder you want to copy and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in the navigation bar to get the path of that folder.
2. Now open up terminal and type

   ```
   rsync -rv --partial /path/on/the/hard/drive /folder/you/want/to/copy/to
   ```
3. Now it will start copying. You'll see a list of files being copied. If it gets stuck on some point, it will either throw up an error message or be stuck. The latter probably means it's copying a large file. Have some patience and and just wait for it to copy.

That's it.

Comment: Its better to use the **--partial** switch which will keep the already transferred files in the directory where the files are being copied in case of an interruption.

Comment: Answer edited appropriately

Comment: I tried with this command but I got 

rsync: link_stat "/media/aab/My" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/aab/Passport" failed: No such file or directory (2)

also I tried to copy the content folder by folder (drag and drop) but everytimes it is frozen.
Any suggestion!!!

Comment: You need to prepend spaces by the `\ ` character. So copying a directory named `two words` would go like this `rsync -rv --partial /path/on/the/hard/drive/two\ words/ /folder/you/want/to/copy/to
`